LaTexIT: \mapsfrom does not work
I need to use the \mapsfrom symbol in LaTexIT . It flags: 8 Undefined control symbol.
Do you know of a way to fix it?
ETA: I use it in TexShop where it works using the expected use-package command. However, in LaTexIT application, specifying usepackage does not work. When I type \mapsfrom in LaTexIT it flags the undefined control symbol. How can I make sure that LaTexIT recognises this symbol? The answers below do not work in that environment.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

latex doesn't define a \mapsfrom command neither in the format nor using amssymb package, so that name being undefined is the expected behaviour. If you saw some documentation of the command it probably mentioned a package that defines it (unicode-math package for example)

Command $\mapsfrom$˛is define the package stmaryrd:
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}     % <---

\begin{document}
\verb+\mapsto+: $\mapsto$, \verb+\mapsfrom+: $\mapsfrom$
\end{document}



Thanks, my main problem was that I did not know how to use the preamble in LaTeXit, which Pierre Chatelier kindly helped me out with in the mean time. Indeed, stmaryrd works once added.


Unfortunately, after literally decades of asking for \mapsfrom, AMSSYMB still does not provide it. That explains your error message.

stmaryrd or fdsymbol do provide it.


In order to still use amssymb and ONLY \mapsfrom from fdsymbol,
Importing single symbol from FdSymbol
has the answer. Look there, answer by Henry Menke - also same Menke shows in commentary how to find out about the font table, e.g. \mapsfrom is 42 (of, course ;- D.Adams) (NOT "42, that's hex)
